# Why I can't import my own module in python?

Tags: python

I had trying a app using Flask.
I'm used [my package `UsefulDeveloperTools`](https://github.com/penghao123456/UsefulDeveloperTools).
Its `__init__.py`like this: (`__init__.py`)

```py
"""
Useful Tools.
"""

import threads
import IDgenerator
```

And its directory is like this: (directories

```
.
\ __init__.py
\ threads.py
\ IDgenerator.py
```

And I pushed it in [TestPyPI](https://test.pypi.org/project/UsefulDeveloperTools/0.2.2/) and installed it in my virtual environment used `python3 -m pip install --upgrade --index-url https://test.pypi.org/simple/ --no-deps UsefulDeveloperTools`.

And I have activated my environment,
and run following code use `python3 main.py`: (main.py)

```py
import flask
from threading import Thread
import time
import random
import UsefulDeveloperTools # Error this
import logging

app=flask.Flask(__name__)
# unimportance
```

But python raised an error: (terminal)

```
(Blog) phao@phao-virtual-machine:~/桌面/pypoj/Blog$ python3 main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/phao/桌面/pypoj/Blog/main.py", line 5, in <module>
    import UsefulDeveloperTools
  File "/home/phao/桌面/pypoj/Blog/lib/python3.10/site-packages/UsefulDeveloperTools/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    import threads
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'threads'
```

Why? What wronged? How can I finish it?

P.S. This is my packages in my environment: (terminal)

```
(Blog) phao@phao-virtual-machine:~/桌面/pypoj/Blog$ pip list
Package              Version
-------------------- -------
click                8.1.3
Flask                2.2.2
itsdangerous         2.1.2
Jinja2               3.1.2
Markdown             3.4.1
MarkupSafe           2.1.1
pip                  22.3.1
setuptools           59.6.0
UsefulDeveloperTools 0.2.2
Werkzeug             2.2.2
```

Comment: You need to turn what you have in your git repository into a proper, installable Python package, please refer to the [packaging guide](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/).

Comment: When you look in the `/home/phao/桌面/pypoj/Blog/lib/python3.10/site-packages/UsefulDeveloperTools` folder, do you see an installed copy of `threads.py`?

Comment: Yes, I can. @KarlKnechtel

Comment: I'm following this tutorial and uploaded the package in TestPyPI. @metatoaster

Comment: You now need to install your package into your environment, e.g. run `pip install -e .` in the root of your package, or install the resulting wheel (which makes your project not editable for the environment, thus this is not recommended).

Comment: But if he want's to use this package within some other context and is not in the development scope of this project, I assume it's better to load it from pypi instead.

Answer (score 2):

I looked on your repo and you are not following the packaging guide at all. You should reorganize your code in a proper file structure and set up eg. a pyproject.toml.
Python has an easy tutorial regarding packaging you can find here:
https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects.html

Additionally your `__init__.py` is wrong. There are several options how you can put imports in your init file. The closes to what you attemptet would be to place a dot before the module names. But I don't know if that helps, before fixing the general package.

```py
"""
Useful Tools.
"""

import .threads
import .IDgenerator
```

Check out this article for different options for init styles:
https://towardsdatascience.com/whats-init-for-me-d70a312da583

Comment: Please don't post links as answers, rather summarize the main information to make you answer self sufficient. You can leave the link as reference but provide all necessary info

Comment: @mozway the answer contained more than just the link, but I edited anyway. Hope, you appreciate it.

Comment: I followed this tutorial.

Comment: @phao cool, is it working now? You can flag my answer as accepted solution and you could edit your question to include what you finally did to get it running.

Comment: No, it doesn't. It says: `SyntaxError: invalid syntax.`.@FordPrefect

Comment: That is somthing else @phao. You better update your question and describe what you did and post the full error description.

Answer (score -1):

if you have made the module then keep it in the same directory as your file and run it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: But I'm packaged and uploaded my package in TestPyPI and installed it in my environment, so it was in mypython third-party library path. Is it wrong?